# How can I tell R to apply functions to multiple data?

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop, vegan

I have been stacking this work for quite long time, tried different approaches but couldn't succeed.

what I want is to apply following 4 functions to 30 different data (data1,2,3,...data30) within for loop or whatsoever in R. These datasets have same (10) column numbers and different rows.

This is the code I wrote for first data (data1). It works well.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data1)){
  data1$simp <-diversity(data1$sp, "simpson")
  data1$shan <-diversity(data1$sp, "shannon")
  data1$E <- E(data1$sp)
  data1$D <- D(data1$sp)
}
```

I want to apply this code for other 29 data in order not to repeat the process 29 times.

Following code what I am trying to do now. But still not right.

```
data.list <- list(data1, data2,data3,data4,data5)
for(i in data.list){
  data2 <- NULL
  i$simp <-diversity(i$sp, "simpson")
  i$shan <-diversity(i$sp, "shannon")
  i$E <- E(i$sp)
  i$D <- D(i$sp)
  data2 <- rbind(data2, i)
  print(data2)
}
```

So I wanna ask how I can tell R to apply functions to other 29 data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `Map`.

```
fun <- function(DF){
  for(i in 1:nrow(DF)){
    DF$simp <-diversity(DF$sp, "simpson")
    DF$shan <-diversity(DF$sp, "shannon")
    DF$E <- E(DF$sp)
    DF$D <- D(DF$sp)
  }
  DF
}

result.list <- Map(fun, data.list)
```

Or, if you don't want to have a function `fun` in the `.GlobalEnv`, with `lapply`.

```
result.list <- lapply(data.list, function(DF){
  for(i in 1:nrow(DF)){
    DF$simp <-diversity(DF$sp, "simpson")
    DF$shan <-diversity(DF$sp, "shannon")
    DF$E <- E(DF$sp)
    DF$D <- D(DF$sp)
  }
  DF
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options, here's one using only base functions:

```
data.list <- list(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5)
changed_data <- lapply(data.list, function(my_data) {
    my_data$simp <-diversity(my_data$sp, "simpson")
    my_data$shan <-diversity(my_data$sp, "shannon")
    my_data$E <- E(my_data$sp)
    my_data$D <- D(my_data$sp)
    my_data})
```

Comment: ok, here is question? I have 30 different data frames (data1,2, so on). So I am confused withi which data along with its column I wanna use should I choose? if I choose data1$sp, how about others?

Comment: You do not choose any, you use  `my_data` which is the parameter of the function inside `lapply`

Comment: thank you for your time all! I tried all of above. each one gives me this error: "Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' "

Comment: I am sorry. I have found out what was the error. it was because of my panic I chosen  wrong variable for vegan package and I wanna say thank you very much, really appreciated. All codes you suggested work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, it you're ultimately asking about your 'data2' variable and how to merge these all together?  I think the issue you're having is that you're setting `data2 <- NULL` with each loop iteration.  The proposed solution below moves this definition outside the loop and the call to `rbind()` should now append all your data frames together to return the consolidated dataset.

```
data.list <- list(data1, data2,data3,data4,data5) #all 29 can go here
data2 <- NULL
for(i in data.list){

  i$simp <-diversity(i$sp, "simpson")
  i$shan <-diversity(i$sp, "shannon")
  i$E <- E(i$sp)
  i$D <- D(i$sp)
  data2 <- rbind(data2, i)
}
print(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your data1, ..., dataN are files stored in a directory and you're reading them one at a time. Also they have the same header.

What you can do is to import them one at a time and then perform the operations you want, as you mentioned:

```
files <- list.files(directoryPath) #maybe you can grep() some specific files
for (f in files){
  data <- read.table(f) #choose header, sep and so on...
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    data$simp <-diversity(data$sp, "simpson")
    data$shan <-diversity(data$sp, "shannon")
    data$E <- E(data$sp)
    data$D <- D(data$sp)
  }
}
```

be careful that you must be in the working directory or you must add a path to the filename while reading the tables (i.e. `paste(path, f, sep="")`)